# cannot replace trigger, but can drop and create

Tags: sql, db2

While running some DDL on a database I noticed the following

- My user id does not seem to have the permission to replace a trigger:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
  <trigger definition follows>

  DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
  valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
  SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the
  required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization
  ID: "DB2INST1".  Operation: "REPLACE TRIGGER". Object:
  "MYSCHEMA.MY_TRIGGER".  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42501
  ```
- It is, however, able to DROP and CREATE

  ```
  DROP TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
  DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

  CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
  <trigger definition follows>
  DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
  ```

So my question is:

- What is the permission that is needed, to allow for the REPLACE to work?
- Why would this behaviour happen? It appears that despite being denied some permission, I am actually able to carry out the operation it is denying. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) "To replace an existing trigger, the authorization ID of the statement must be the owner of the existing trigger (SQLSTATE 42501)."

If your authid creates the trigger, then your authid can replace it.

From your error message, it appears that the account that created the trigger is different from the account attempting to replace it.

Comment: Ohh.. can you add a link to the doc, I somehow couldn't find it